# List all possible license plate numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

The length of license plate numbers is 6, with 2 letters and 4 numbers.

The first two characters are letters and the last four are numbers. Example: AA1234.

This is the code I have so far:

```
letterCombinations = Tuples[Alphabet[], 2];
numberCombinations = Tuples[Range[0,9], 4];
```

I tried to use `Outer` to combine the lists of letters and the lists of numbers, but it failed. How can I fix it, I want output like this:

```
{{a,a,1,1,1,1},......}
```

Is `Outer` a suitable?

Comment: How did you use `Outer`? Please show us the attempt.

Comment: As there are 6760000 possible license plates in the scheme you mentioned in the question, are you sure you really want to generate them all? If you only need a lot (but not all) maybe randomly generating as many as you need is a better solution. Try: `With[{l := RandomChoice[Alphabet[]], n := RandomInteger[9]}, {l, l, n,
   n, n, n}]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use

```
a = Alphabet[]; (* letter *)
d = Range[0, 9]; (* digit *)

result = Tuples[{a, a, d, d, d, d}];
```

Answer (score 6):

you can definitely use `Outer` if you prefer

```
a = Alphabet[];
b = Range[0,9];
list = Flatten[Outer[List, a,a,b,b,b,b], 5];
list//Length
(* 6760000 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show how this can be done using the OP's proposed approach:

```
Flatten[Outer[Join, letterCombinations, numberCombinations, 1], 1]
```

The other responses are ~ 10x faster.